# spring boot data jpa DataIntegrityViolationException EntityExistsException

Tags: hibernate, jpa

there are two entities `Permission` and `Role` with relation `@ManyToMany`; i want to add some extra field in their join table ,and i coded following this article [enter link description here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/),here my code:
**Role entity**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@GenericGenerator(name = "jpa-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "jpa-uuid")
    private String id;

    @JsonIgnore @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = false,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<RolePermission> role_permission;

    public void addPermission(Permission permission){
        RolePermission rolePermission  = new RolePermission(this,permission);
        role_permission.add(rolePermission);
        permission.getRole_permission().add(rolePermission);
    }
    public void removePermission(Permission permission){
        for(Iterator<RolePermission> iterator = role_permission.iterator();iterator.hasNext();){
            RolePermission rolePermission = iterator.next();
            if(rolePermission.getRole().equals(this) && rolePermission.getPermission().equals(permission)){
                iterator.remove();
                rolePermission.getRole().role_permission.remove(rolePermission);
                rolePermission.setRole(null);
                rolePermission.setPermission(null);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Role role = (Role) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, role.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

**Permission entity**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@GenericGenerator(name = "jpa-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
public class Permission {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "jpa-uuid")
    private String id;

    @JsonIgnore @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "permission",cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<RolePermission> role_permission;

    public void addRole(Role role){
        RolePermission rolePermission  = new RolePermission(role,this);
        role_permission.add(rolePermission);
        role.getRole_permission().add(rolePermission);
    }
    public void removeRole(Role role){
        for(Iterator<RolePermission> iterator = role_permission.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){
            RolePermission rolePermission = iterator.next();
            if(rolePermission.getRole().equals(role) && rolePermission.getPermission().equals(this)){
                iterator.remove();
                rolePermission.getRole().getRole_permission().remove(rolePermission);
                rolePermission.setRole(null);
                rolePermission.setPermission(null);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Permission that = (Permission) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

**Role Permission Key**

```
@Embeddable
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RolePermissionKey implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4686642987484483168L;
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private String role_id;
    @Column(name = "permission_id")
    private String permission_id;

    public RolePermissionKey(String roleId, String permissionId) {
        this.role_id=roleId;
        this.permission_id=permissionId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        RolePermissionKey that = (RolePermissionKey) o;
        return role_id.equals(that.role_id) &&
                permission_id.equals(that.permission_id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(role_id, permission_id);
    }
}
```

**relation table with a extra field**

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RolePermission implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8274025418699729303L;

    @EmbeddedId
    RolePermissionKey id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("role_id")
    Role role;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("permission_id")
    Permission permission;

    Date create_date  =new Date();


    public RolePermission(Role role,Permission permission) {
        this.role=role;
        this.permission=permission;
        this.id = new RolePermissionKey(role.getId(),permission.getId());
        this.create_date=new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        RolePermission that = (RolePermission) o;
        return Objects.equals(role, that.role) &&
                Objects.equals(permission, that.permission);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(role, permission);
    }
}
```

**test code**

```
        Role role5 = roleRepository.findByTitle("Role5");
        Permission permission6 = permissionRepository.findByTitle("Permission6");
        role5.addPermission(permission6);
        permission6.addRole(role5);
        roleRepository.save(role5);
        permissionRepository.save(permission6);
```

Then , i used the same  test code in  four place for test:
**1. a class implements ApplicationRunner ;initialize data before spring boot startup , `no exception`**
**2. a spring boot test class @SpringBootTest;`no exception`**
**3. a controller class @Controller ; `exception thrown`**
**4. a serviceclass @Service ; `exception thrown`**
**Here the exception:**
`2020-05-05 09:11:35.952  WARN 17000 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.xxx.model.authentication.RolePermission#com.xxx.model.authentication.RolePermissionKey@9e2c8771]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.xxx.model.authentication.RolePermission#com.xxx.model.authentication.RolePermissionKey@9e2c8771]]`

now i'm confused whether the problem is code or some else.I have used test code in 1,2 to add a relation between
a role and a permission susscessfully ,and got  the expected result .But code not work in 3,4.

 I need some tips and advices; by the way , are there any open source real world projects worth learning that use spring data jpa 
, thank you.

`#################################################################`
thanks for @ Olivier Depriester's help.
I had investigated the elements of RolePermission Set in both Role and Permission Entity in debug model;
the type of the collection maintaining the relation of two entities is `set`,and I have overwrite the `equals()` and 
`hashCode()` method which could ensure a relation entity (RolePermission) with same ID won't appear in the same set.
before the `save()` execution, there is actually only one RolePermission object contained in both Set of Role and Permision.
In the test code, there are two `.save()` action ,even if I comment one of them , the exception will also thrown.
I am wondering if there is a problem with the `cascade`.
It's weird that test code can be executed sucessfully somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `role5.get().addPermission(permission6);`, you create and persist (*) a `RolePermission` for `role5` and `permission6`.

When you call `permission6.addRole(role5);`, you create and persist an other  `RolePermission` for `role5` and `permission6`.

==> Exception : 2 instances of the same entity with the same hashcode in session.

(*) When you add an item to an attribute of a persisted object, this item is automatically persisted. And as you get `role5` and `permission6` from their repository, they are persisted objects

Thus, you need to modify your code to create 1 single `RolePermission` that you can assign to both `Role` and `Permission`